# Using rabbitmq to send String/Custom Object from one spring boot application to another

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

My requirement is to for starters send a string from one spring-boot application to another using AMQP.

I am new to it and I have gone through [this spring-boot guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/), so i know the basic fundamentals of Queue, Exchange, Binding, Container and listener.

So, above guide shows the steps when amqp is received in same application.

I am a little confused on where to start if I want to achieve above type of communication between 2 different spring-boot applications.

What are the properties needed for that, etc.

Let me know if any details required.

Answer (score 1):

Just divide the application into two:

1. One without Receiver and ...
2. Another without Sender

Make sure your application and configuration etc stays the same. With Spring boot's built-in RabbitMQ, you will be able to run it alright.

Next step is to call sender as and when needed from your business logic.

Comment: Okay I'll try that and I think I also need some propeties to be set on both applications. Properties like spring.rabbitmq.host, spring.rabbitmq.addresses, spring.rabbitmq.port, etc

Comment: Okay, I got it working, didn't need to define any extra properties like I said above

Comment: about the last part "call sender as and when needed from business logic".
I have sender in application one and receiver in application 2, so does my business logic need to stay on sender side and not on receiver side, since when I'm in receiver side, I can't call sender. Is my understanding right?

Comment: One of my senior has told that I will need both sender and receiver on both applications, but then the problem comes for them to know that one has to receive messages from other one or something like that...

Comment: By nature, the rabbitMQ (and all AMQP or any Queue) logic is asynchronous -- even though you can emulate an RPC using the queue. That means, sender sends a message and usually not waiting for any reply and goes its business. The receiver also does something (some business logic) but sender initiates it. I  hope this clarifies.